# Operator overloading for std::set is not working properly

Tags: c++, sorting, set, operator-overloading, structure

```
struct Buffer
 {     
      const char* data;
      u_int32_t size;
      u_int32_t sequenceNumber;         

      bool operator < (const Buffer &rhs) const
      {   
           return sequenceNumber > rhs.sequenceNumber;     
      }
  };

  std::set<Buffer>bufferData;


  void RemoveElementsFromBuffer(u_int32_t _sequenceNumber)//remove data smaller than _sequenceNumber
  {
       Buffer _packetInformation;
       set<Buffer >::iterator _iterator;
       while(bufferData.begin() != bufferData.end())
       {
           _iterator = bufferData.begin();
           _packetInformation = *_iterator;
           if(_packetInformation.sequenceNumber > _sequenceNumber)
                break; 
           bufferData.erase(_iterator);  
           delete [] _packetInformation.data;
       } 
   }
```

The packets inside `bufferdata` are usually in ascending order. I am inserting sorted values but deleting any random number. Sometimes this set is unsorted. Do not understanding why this is happening. Is it a problem of operator overloading?

Comment: Please post a minimal code sample that reproduces the problem. Note you don't need to include operators `>` or `==`.

Comment: Why don't I need them?

Comment: You don't need them for `std::set<Buffer>` to function properly. Also note that the way you have implemented the `<` and `>` operators is extremely confusing! Why put the RHS on the LHS?

Comment: is `<` the only one used for comparison?

Comment: Yes, that is correct (although you can also instantiate the `set` template with a custom comparator.)

Comment: Thanks. Is there any problem with the `<`operator overloading? Don't understand why the data is sometimes unsorted!!

Comment: Your operator looks fine. You should post the minimal code sample I mentioned in the first comment.

Comment: I have edited my code to give a minimal example. Thanks.

Comment: Does this example, when run, produce thr described problem?  How is `data` related to the described problem?  Are there any `const_cast`s in your code?  How about C style casts involving `Buffer` or pointers to same?  Do you modify `Buffer`s that are in the `set` while in the `set`?  How is the set populated?

Comment: Not all the time it produces the described problem. It happens when large amount of inserts and erases has been performed. No there are no casts in my code. I don't ever modify `data`. I populate `data` through constructor. But the parameter for the `data` is populated by using `memcpy` on another `const char*`.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem here is that your `operator<` is wrong. You're sorting *descending* not ascending, so all your other code won't work right. So first you need to fix `operator<` to `return sequenceNumber < rhs.sequenceNumber;`.

Next you need to decide if your function removes elements smaller than the one requested (from the comment) or smaller than/equal to (actual code).

Then for bonus points you can use `lower_bound` to find the end element to iterator over, instead of getting `begin` and erasing it over and over again.